# read system call junk characters

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I'm trying to read in user input for a file name, to which I then attempt to open the file specified. The problem I'm getting is that there seems to be junk characters added on to the end of the input. (I discovered this when trying to printf() the userInput variable).

```
if(read(0, userInput, 128) < 0)
    write(2, "An error occurred in the read.\n", 31);
```

Any idea what's going wrong?
I got this code right from codewiki
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted enough info to post a definite answer, but here's my educated guess:

C strings are null terminated. If you read only a partial string and don't terminate it, but try to print it as a C string, you'll get undefined behaviour - in practice, you'll see the garbage following it.

Comment: Ok, so does this mean that I have to append a Null character manually after reading from the user? Also I did try strcat(userInput, "\0") but still ended up getting junk

Comment: After the above code I have                               printf("CHECK1 %s CHECK2", userInput);
 printf("SECOND %s PART", userInput);
to check if it read properly, but I end up getting those weird symbols after the string is printed ( after the %s in the printf statement)

Comment: `strcat` only works on C strings. catch-22 (BTW that's a no-op). `input[pos] = 0`

Comment: hmm, any idea on what I could use then to find the length of the string (being that its length depends on the user)?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, Thanks for the help Karoly! For anybody else who may look at this, here's what I did: nRead = read(0,userInput,128);
  userInput[nRead-1] = '\0';

Comment: there are 3 things to consider: 1) still do the error checking 2) Off-by-one error